# I can only water lawn by manually opening the bleed screw

Tags: valve, sprinkler-system, troubleshooting

My sprinklers in one zone won't  go on unless I open the bleed screw. I replaced the whole valve and yet still, in that one zone, I can only water the lawn by opening the bleed screw instead of it going on automatically like it is supposed to.

What do I do??

Answer (score 1):

Are you confident that the voltage necessary to operate the valve is reaching the valve? You are performing a manual mechanical operation with the bleed screw. A new valve will behave as you describe if the wiring is interrupted.

Consider to swap wiring with an adjacent valve. The new valve would operate properly and the old, formerly working valve should fail if the wiring or continuity is the problem/solution.